How to jump back to the page I've come from after I've clicked a link in OneNote on iOS?
I use linking extensively in OneNote and the ability to jump backwards and forwards through the history of pages I've been either selecting or jumping to through a link is essential.
However on iOS I can't work out how to jump back to the page I've come from after I've clicked a link. Is this possible?
